# CSS2renderer is not working with webgl renderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

when we add css2renderer on time like label then my screen stuck seems like orbit control is not working .I’m using transform control in my project and its also not working when annotation label add on model with add listener.

```
let div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    div.className = 'label';
    div.textContent = '+';
    div.type='button';
    div.id='label6';
    div.style.marginTop = '-1em';  div.addEventListener("mousedown",scope_AC.uiHandler.addConnectionBtns,false);
    let label = new CSS2DObject( div );
    label.position.copy(pos);
    childModel.add( label );
    scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );  scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '15px';
scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that CSS2DRenderer is itself a DOM element above the canvas and thus the canvas never receives the mouse events. Set the labelRenderer as such:

```
labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

See also the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/css3d-tooltips-three-2l9v5?file=/index.js:1189-1243